# In Rails how do I handle multiple, polymorphic file uploads with jquery-file-upload and CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, polymorphism, carrierwave

In my project I currently have different models (Project, Message, etc) that:

```
has_many :assets, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
```

Each Asset is basically a model with a CarrierWave file. Normally I would just use accepted_nested_attributes on the parent model (Project, Message, etc) and have the file upload fields listed in a fields_for block.

My problem is that since I'm using jQuery-File-Uploader with AJAX the parent model's form will call the parent model's Create method when ever a file is uploaded. The rest of the parent model fields might not be filled out yet. I'm thinking maybe I could have the file uploader call the create method in the Assets controller, but then I would some how have to send the parent model's class so the polymorphic association is stored correctly.

Any ideas of how I might get this working cleanly? Thanks for looking.

Comment: You could allow the model to be saved with just the upload present – but mark it as being in an 'incomplete' state. Then when the additional fields in the form are submitted you can include a hidden field that updates the 'incomplete' state to indicate that you should now run validations against these additional fields.

Update your create method so that it does a find first and then a create.

Comment: Actually after the file has uploaded and the parent model has been created you could update the form action using js to point to the update action instead.

Comment: uploadify makes it a lot easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK.

## Step 1

add `gem 'carrier wave'` to you Gemfile

## Step 2

save the code to `/lib/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb`

```
require 'rack/utils'

class FlashSessionCookieMiddleware
  def initialize(app, session_key = '_session_id')
    @app = app
    @session_key = session_key
  end

  def call(env)
    if env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /^(Adobe|Shockwave) Flash/
      req = Rack::Request.new(env)
      env['HTTP_COOKIE'] = [ @session_key,
                             req.params[@session_key] ].join('=').freeze unless req.params[@session_key].nil?
      env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = "#{req.params['_http_accept']}".freeze unless req.params['_http_accept'].nil?
    end

    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

## Step3

edit `session_store.rb` add the code to the end of file

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before(
  ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore,
  FlashSessionCookieMiddleware,
  Rails.application.config.session_options[:key]
)
```

## Step4

Download jquery.uploadify.js from [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/wp-content/uploads/uploadify-v2.1.4.zip) and unzip it.

## Step5

1. Copy `jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js` & `swfobject.js` to
   `/app/assets/javascripts` if you use Rails3.1 or later, to
   `/public/javascripts` if you use Rails 3.0 or before version.
2. Copy `uploadify.swf` and `cancel.png` to `/app/assets/images/` or
   `/public/images`
3. Copy `uploadify.css` to `/app/assets/stylesheets/` or
   `/public/stylesheets`

## Step6

Edit your application.js, insert below code to it

```
//= require swfobject
//= require jquery.uploadify
```

## Step7

In you upload page, add this

```
<input id="uploadify" name="uploadify" type="file" />
```

## Step8

add this code to you upload page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  <% key = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key] %>
  var uploadify_script_data = {};
  var csrf_param = $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content');
  var csrf_token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
  uploadify_script_data[csrf_param] = encodeURI(encodeURIComponent(csrf_token));
  uploadify_script_data['<%= key %>'] = '<%= cookies[key] %>';

  $('#uploadify').uploadify({
    uploader        : '/assets/uploadify.swf',
    script          : '/photos',
    cancelImg       : '/images/cancel.png',
    auto            : true,
    multi           : true,
    removeCompleted : true,
    scriptData      : uploadify_script_data,
    onComplete      : function(event, ID, fileObj, doc, data) {
    }
  });
});
```

## Step9

Write your controller like this

```
def create
  @photo = Photo.new(:image => params[:Filedata])
  @photo.save
end
```